# Django annotate on float field is not working properly

Tags: django, django-queryset, django-annotate

I'm using **Django 2.2**

I have the following model structure

```
class Location(models.Model):
  name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  country_name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
  latitude = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)
  longitude = models.FloatField(null=True, blank=True)


class TrackingData(models.Model):
  location = models.ForeignKey(Location)
```

I want to select latitude and count of the number of same latitudes

```
data = TrackingData.objects.filter(locaiton__latitude__isnull=False).values(latitude=F('location__latitude')).annotate(count=Count('latitude'))
```

I'm getting the results as

```
<TrackingDataQuerySet [{'latitude': 28.6324823, 'count': 1}, {'latitude': 28.6324823, 'count': 1}, {'latitude': 28.6324823, 'count': 1}, {'latitude': 28.6324823, 'count': 1}, {'latitude': 28.6324823, 'count': 1}, {'latitude': 28.6324823, 'count': 1}, {'latitude': 28.6324823, 'count': 1}]>
```

All latitudes are same, still getting separate results, instead, I want

```
<TrackingDataQuerySet [{'latitude': 28.6324823, 'count': 7}]>
```

> Edit 2

Output of `print(data.query)`

```
SELECT `tracking_location`.`latitude` AS `latitude`, COUNT(`tracking_location`.`latitude`) AS `count` FROM `tracking_trackingdata` INNER JOIN `tracking_location` ON (`tracking_trackingdata`.`location_id` = `tracking_location`.`id`) WHERE `tracking_location`.`address` IS NOT NULL GROUP BY `tracking_location`.`latitude`, `tracking_trackingdata`.`scan_time`, `tracking_trackingdata`.`created` ORDER BY `tracking_trackingdata`.`scan_time` DESC, `tracking_trackingdata`.`created` DESC
```

Comment: Is `28.63.24.823` a valid float value?

Comment: Sorry that was a typo error. Fixed.

Comment: what is the result of `print(data.query)` ?

Comment: Check `Edit 2` in the question for the output of `print(data.query)`

Answer (score 0):

```
data = TrackingData.objects.filter(locaiton__latitude__isnull=False).values(latitude=F('location__latitude').distinct()).annotate(count=Count('latitude'))
```

Comment: It gives error `AttributeError: 'F' object has no attribute 'distinct'`